# Integrating existing gwt application in grails

Tags: gwt, grails

i have such a task and I would like some advices on how to do this. Maybe someone already done such a work or know some usefull articles. Where does *.gwt.xml files go, where does client / public / server / index.html file go, servlet mapping from web.xml, etc, etc.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the [Grails GWT Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/gwt) and port your application over. For back-end I've used both the GWT-RPC way with [Grails DTO Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/dto) or you can use your Controllers and make HTTP RequestFactory calls in your client and communicate via JSON.